# Hajr Aswad and the First Covenant

Tags: hadith, source-identification, authenticity

Is there such a report in which the Black Stone is the depository of the written Primordial Covenant? Supposedly it was related from Aisha RA according to the article right [here](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/ibrahim-hindy/living-abrahams-legacy-relevance-of-rites-and-rituals-in-the-modern-age) at footnote 17. Unfortunately the authors fell short of quoting the exact report.

Can someone help find the report from the source offered? Are there other sources in which this report is found and is it authentic?

Comment: Relevant: [Mustadrak al-Hakim](https://al-maktaba.org/book/2266/1714) and [Musannaf Abd al-Razzaaq](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32856/9578)